# average salary after each entry of new row js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to make function which counting average salary after each entry of new row.
This is how my code looks

```
function addNew() {

  let salary = prompt("What is your salary?");
  element.innerHTML += `<li> 
    <span class = "employeeSalary"> ${salary}</span>
  </li>`
}
```

I have to use pure js for it. This is where I started, but I can't really get how to do this

```
function countAvgSal() {
  const num = document.getElementsByClassName("employeeSalary");
} 

countAvgSal();

function writeSal() {
    const docavg = document.getElementById('docAvgSal');
    docavg.innerHTML = `The average salary is ${countAvgSal()}`
}
```

Comment: Where is `element` declared?  Is there a specific issue you are facing?

Comment: let element = document.getElementById("employeeList");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate average you could use the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

But first you need to get all the salaries. `.getElementsByClassName` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). To convert it to a list of numbers you could use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const salaries = [...document.getElementsByClassName("employeeSalary")];
```

And then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) this array to an array of numbers:

```
salaries.map(e => parseFloat(e.innerHTML))
```

Finally you use `.reduce()` to calculate the average:

```
.reduce((sum, cur) => sum += cur) / salaries.length;
```

```js
function addNew() {
  const element = document.getElementById('salaries');
  let salary = prompt("What is your salary?");
  element.innerHTML += `<li> 
    <span class = "employeeSalary"> ${salary}</span>
  </li>`;
  writeSal();
}

function countAvgSal(){
  const salaries = [...document.getElementsByClassName("employeeSalary")];
  return !salaries.length ? 0 : salaries.map(e => parseFloat(e.innerHTML))
    .reduce((sum, cur) => sum += cur) / salaries.length;
} 

function writeSal(){
    const docavg = document.getElementById('docAvgSal');
    docavg.innerHTML = `The average salary is ${countAvgSal()}`
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addNew()">Add</button>
<ul id="salaries"></ul>
<div id="docAvgSal"></div>
```